# How do I create Mobile Web Form in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows-phone-7, web-applications, mobile, windows-mobile

I have to create mobile website in visual studio 2010.But there is no templte in visual studio of Mobile Web Form.
I use Default Web Form and using Following code ::

```
   <mobile:Label ID="lblHeading"  runat="server" EnableViewState="False" StyleReference="StyleHeader" Wrapping="Wrap">
</mobile:Label>
```

Is it any other way to create Mobile Web Form and actual way of flow of Mobile Web Site Development..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have `Windows Phone 7`, but I know you will need to download and install the [Windows Phone 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570), then start your Visual Studio and pick one of the new `Windows Phone 7` projects.